# Trying to output a User.fname from an associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So, I'm a beginner in Rails and I'm having a problem outputting the data I need.

I have tables users, posts, and comments.
I should be able to, verified in the console, ask for Comment.find(32).user.fname and get the first name of the commenter on a blog I've created.

I already figured out and was able to code to retrieve Comment.post.id and use that information.  Why can't I get the user.fname?

My code in the post index.html.erb looks like this:

```
<ul>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

    <li class="post"><%= post.body %>  |  <%= post.user_id %></li> 
    <li class="links"><%= link_to 'Show', post %>  |  
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>  |  
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></li>

    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>

      <% if comment.post.id == post.id %> <!-- I need below:Comment.find(32).user.fname -->
        <li class="comment"> <%= comment.body %> <%= comment.user.fname %> <br/> </li> 
      <% else %>

      <% end %>
    <% end %>   
<% end %>
```

The part above it where ask for <% if comment.post.id == post.id %> works.  I'm confused as to why i can't ask for comment.user.fname.

My associations are set up as well and like I said, I can grab the info in the console.

Any help is appreciated ... thanks!

As requested: my models:

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts, foreign_key: "user_id" 

has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", class_name: "Relationship", dependent: :destroy
has_many :followeds, through: :relationships
has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: :followed_id, class_name: "Relationship", dependent: :destroy
has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

validates_presence_of :fname, :lname, :username, :password

has_many :comments
end
```

Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

Comment:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post

end
```

And a Relationship table I have:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
    validates_uniqueness_of :follower_id, scope: :followed_id

end
```

Output from Console that verifies I should be able to get the data:
    [41] pry(main)> Comment.find(30).user.fname
  Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 30]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
=> "c"

From my controller:

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
```

Actually I only bring in @posts, should I also bring in @users or @comments or params?  I don't think I should have to.  I think I've tried that in the past as well.

Adding error message:

undefined method `fname' for nil:NilClass

Adding my routes just in case that may be the issue but I don't see how:

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :users do 
    member do
      post 'follow'
      post 'unfollow'
    end
  end
```

Comment: show us your models (user, comment, post) associations.

Comment: It doesn't print the line: `<li class="comment"> <%= comment.body %> <%= comment.user.fname %> <br/> </li>` or just the `comment.user.fname`? Are you sure that user has `fname` available, I mean if it's not blank?

Comment: It does print <%= comment.body %>, it doesn't print <%= comment.user.fname %> ... I've placed my console output above.  Maybe the data isn't all available to the index?  I'll place the code from my controller as well.  Maybe I'm missing bringing in something?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to take @users or @comments from db separately. Rails will query them when you try to access its parameters.

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

will be enough.

You can get username of user who commented it just like

```
<%= comment.user.fname %>
```

or name of person who made the post like:

```
<%= post.user.fname %>
```

If it doesn't give you username, maybe you have an empty name in user model, or current comment has no connection to user ? Can you post your error here if you got any ?

Comment: Sure thing, thanks.... it's an: undefined method `fname' for nil:NilClass ... error referencing that line.  So, the comment shows but of course, I want the user name of the commenter to show up afterward.  Oh, and I cleared the table 2 days ago to specifically make sure all the data was there and they all have names.  I even validate for it. (not bad for my 2nd week in rails huh? - really appreciate all the help)

Comment: It's really weird.  So in the earlier line I changed <li class="post"><%= post.body %>  |  <%= post.user_id %></li> to <li class="post"><%= post.body %>  |  <%= post.user.fname %></li>  and that works too.  It's just the later line with comment.user.fname that will not work ... strange to me.

Comment: can you put there <%= comment.to_s %> and check if it has user_id key ?

Comment: Yep, comments on screen:   YES but am I C? #<Comment:0x007ffe5759ea18> 
Come aagin? #<Comment:0x007ffe5759e798>

Comment: i'm sorry, can you make it `<%= comment.to_json %>`

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to hopefully solve this mystery ... the output is: YES but am I C? {"id":31,"body":"YES but am I C?","user_id":4,"post_id":1,"created_at":"2014-10-14T22:59:39.414Z","updated_at":"2014-10-14T22:59:39.419Z","comment_on":null} 
Come aagin? {"id":32,"body":"Come aagin?","user_id":4,"post_id":1,"created_at":"2014-10-14T23:02:58.469Z","updated_at":"2014-10-14T23:02:58.473Z","comment_on":null} 
Testing again ... {"id":35,"body":"Testing again ... ","user_id":1,"post_id":1,"created_at":"2014-10-16T11:58:37.923Z","updated_at":"2014-10-16T11:58:37.928Z","comment_on":null}

Comment: does it matter how my resources are nested? (Let me post it above)  In my routes I have:   resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :users do 
    member do
      post 'follow'
      post 'unfollow'
    end
  end